# How to determine if hardware permissions are saved in browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have migrated my site from **HTTP** to **HTTPS** and unlike before I see that, once I allow permission for usage of my **Microphone** or **Webcam** it gets saved in  the browser(Chrome), and for further **audio/video** calls it doesn't ask hardware permission. I want to detect if hardware permissions are already saved in browser. How to do it?

**NOTE:-** I need a generic code to work with **Chrome**, **Firefox** and **Safari**. I don't have any idea about this at all, so please don't ask what have I tried.

Comment: Request permissions, and see how long it takes to get a response?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Seems like a good idea, can you please elaborate how to get it done for all browsers (eg:- **webkitGetUserMedia** is for Chrome won't work with Firefox).

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Also **getUserMedia** is called by a plugin that I use for audio/video calls. I may not be able to Request Permission again.